# Convert dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2019

I need to convert "13/10/2021 09:38:20 PM" to "2021/10/13 21:38:20" in SQL Server 2019. I have looked up the internet for the same but I can't find a solution. Please help me.

Comment: use [convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you starting with a bad regional format? Why do you care about what format SQL Server provides? Let SQL Server interpret the ambiguous regional format and present a proper datetime data type (or, better yet, fix the source so it isn't providing ambiguous formats in the first place). If you want to present it as something like `yyyy/mm/dd 24:nn:ss` let the presentation tier do that.

That said, you can do this as follows:

```
DECLARE @BadDateString varchar(32) = '13/10/2021 09:38:20 PM',
        @SaneOutput    datetime;

SET @SaneOutput = CONVERT(datetime, @BadDateString, 103);

SELECT SaneOutput = @SaneOutput,
       BadOutput  = CONVERT(char(11), @SaneOutput, 111)
                  + CONVERT(char(8),  @SaneOutput, 108);
```

Output:

| SaneOutput | BadOutput |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-13 21:38:20.000 | 2021/10/13 21:38:20 |

[This is complex](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05dc134c8cf4a3db96719deb10693066) because the format you want isn't available natively (well, unless you use the [extremely expensive `FORMAT()` function](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) that I'm sure someone will recommend). Lots more about [Dating Responsibly here](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Answer (score 2):

As you have to convert from one format to another format, first you have to convert into datetime datatype and then apply custom format as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @datestring VARCHAR(50) = '13/10/2021 09:38:20 PM'
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,@datestring,103),'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')
```

> 2021/10/13 21:38:20

*References*:

- [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Standard Datetime format strings](https://database.guide/list-of-the-standard-date-time-format-strings-supported-by-the-format-function-in-sql-server/)
- [Custom Datetime format strings](https://database.guide/list-of-the-custom-date-time-format-strings-supported-by-the-format-function-in-sql-server/)

**CAVEAT**: Using 'FORMAT` is expensive. So, make a decision accordingly. [FORMAT is expensive](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Comment: Don’t forget this reference, which shows how bad `format` is at scale: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: @AaronBertrand, understood. It is very expensive. Thanks for the enlightening post. I have updated my answer.